# FIND_IN_SET woth trim function for values

Tags: mysql

I have a column that contains a string of comma delimited values. I use `FIND_IN_SET` to query this column and it works fine until there is a space between the value and the `,`. I cannot control the input. The only solution I have found that works is by running `REPLACE` on the column within the `FIND_IN_SET` function. Unfortunately this will remove all spaces and could return undesired results.

The blow example would return both row in the table as opposed to the first one only.

```
col1                  | col2      
carpet , foo, bar     | myVal1
abc, 123 , car pet    | myVal2
```

Query

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('carpet', REPLACE(col1, ' ', ''));
```

Is there a way of limiting this to only trim the space wither side of the `,`

Comment: the problem you describe matches the bad table design time to learn about normalization..

Comment: If you have access to MySQL server version 8.0, you could use `REGEXP`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm fully aware of the flawed design. I've been tasked with providing a temporary solution while the data issue is addressed

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i've used `REGEX` in the past with MySQL and found it to be extremely slow

Comment: "i've used REGEX in the past with MySQL and found it to be extremely slow " there is no solution for this what would make it fast... FIND_IN_SET is just as bad as REGEXP

Answer (score 4):

You could try replacing `,[ ]` or `[ ],` with just comma:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    FIND_IN_SET('carpet', REPLACE(REPLACE(col1, ', ', ','), ' ,', ',')) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: This answers assumes that there would be at most one leading/trailing space around the commas, *and* that your actual data itself does not contain commas.  If there could arbitrary amount of whitespace, this answer would fail.  In that case, what you would really need is regex replacement.  MySQL 8+ does support this, but a better bet would be to normalize your data and stop storing CSV data like this.

Comment: I think this will not work if there are more than one space characters on either side

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes, I knew this when I answered, but I tried to give a solution for what I perceived to be the exact problem, where this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Ugh, I feel ill.

Comment: Thanks - it's ugly but so is the data :/